# ARCore collider on generated planes

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm just playing around with AR core and want to have an object flying around the room and able to land. I'm unsure about how to add colliders to the planes that ARcore is generating based on the visuals on the room. Would this involve instantiating box colliders on the planes somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ARCore SDK's trackable planes are essentially identified flat surfaces such as the ground or a tabletop.

You can ask the SDK for a list of points for each trackable plane's boundary polygon (retrieved in clockwise order) and create a mesh from those points via triangulation. With the mesh ready, create a GameObject and add a MeshCollider component that references it.

I've created a free Unity plugin that does exactly this. Feel free to use it: https://github.com/jonas-johansson/ARCoreUtils.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Jonas, thank you, this works perfectly and with almost zero effort.

Comment: @DuncanRoberts, I'm really glad to hear that :). Please consider marking the question as answered, to make sure other people find it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are doing this in Unity, you may want to use a Mesh Collider on the surface instead of a Box Collider.

I'm not sure about ARCore in Unity specifically, but in other AR frameworks it works something like in the attached screen shot, so I imagine it would be similar.

[image: Plane with Collider Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry I should have said it was in Unity. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work actually. ARcore has a tracked plane visualiser that I tried adding a mesh collider to but it doesn't seem to help. The issue is that if I add a rigid body to my object, it just falls down constantly and I would like it if it could collide and land in any tracked planes ARcore has registered. Perhaps colliders isn't the best way to do it but if anyone has any advice I'd love to hear.

Answer (score -1):

Adding a rigid body to the object causes gravity to be applied set gravity to 0 on the object rigid bidy. That will stop it falling away