# How can you recognize the floor in Google ARCore?

Tags: arcore

How can you recognize the floor in Google ARCore?

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gk8LswPMITM), a Cube with Rigidbody falls at regular intervals.

After a while the system starts to recognize the floor, but the Cube slips past the floor and falls.

How can I catch the Cube on the floor?

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in Unity?  If so, make sure both the Cube and the TrackedPlane game objects have colliders.

Also, here is another discussion related to adding a MeshCollider to a tracked plane using ARCoreUtils:

[ARCore collider on generated planes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962848/arcore-collider-on-generated-planes/45967704#45967704)

Direct Link to ARCoreUtils:
https://github.com/jonas-johansson/ARCoreUtils

Comment: Does TrackedPlane in this case refer to TrackedPlaneVisualizer? Should I set Mesh Collider on this TrackedPlaneVisualizer? I tried to set it up, but the falling Cube will slip through the floor as well.

Comment: @KuniyasuYakushiji make sure to accept the answer so other users can find the right answer fast in the future.