# ARCore Collider on TrackingPlane in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I would like a spider to wander around the tracking plane in ARcore, but since there is no collider not a single AI script works (I tried tons of them, also ICE - Creature Control and HerdSim) because there is no collider on the ground.

So my last resort is making the trackable plane a collider itself - which [*@JonasJohansson*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2863857/jonas-johansson) already did in this post [ARCore collider on generated planes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962848/arcore-collider-on-generated-planes?answertab=active#tab-top)
Link to the GitHub: https://github.com/jonas-johansson/ARCoreUtils

**Sadly** this does not work anymore because Google updated the scripts (I guess) and it gives 3 errors.

How can we make those scripts work again?

Comment: Hi Danve, I just wanted to let you know that ARCoreUtils now works with ARCore 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARCoreUtils works with ARCore 1.1 now.

Comment: Much love to ARCoreUtils

Answer (score 0):

I created a little plugin to simulate ARCore in the editor so I could play and debug it without deploying to the phone all the time. It also has an option to automatically add colliders to the tracked planes.

[image: Option to add coliiders to tracked planes]

You can find it here: https://github.com/JackM36/Eazy-ARCore-Interface

Code is very similar to native ARCore. Just look at the example scene.

Comment: I cannot +1 because I ain't got enough rep, but thank you!