# How can I make collision on AR plane in Arfoundation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want make Collision on Ar Plane.
Now I using ARfoundation.

In the sample Scene (Called SimpleAR) it made
plane for Place on object.

But it is not Collision so I want make Collision that AR Plane.

Now I Instance a cube + 0.5f Y pos from plane then it pass the AR plane.

What I want is that cube is collide AR Plane.

Is there some tips?

Comment: Read the manual first: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: @shingo I already know about this, have you ever been using AR foundation?? If you've ever experienced AR foundation at least once you couldn't say that. how nice Comment! Thanks

Comment: I have never used Arfoundation either but i am pretty sure it just visualizes the plane and that visualized plane does not have a `collider` or a `mesh` since it is just visualized. I am guessing you want the cube to fall on to the plane. For that you gotta create mesh and add collider to generated mesh or mimic the physics with scripts since you know the position of the plane. Take a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962848/arcore-collider-on-generated-planes) at here how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a MeshCollider inside a "DetectedPlaneVisualizer.cs" script and assign it as shared mesh.

```
//Declare a MeshCollider inside DetectedPlaneVisualizer.cs

private MeshCollider ar_meshCollider;



//Initialize inside Awake() function

ar_meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();



//Assign as shared mesh inside _UpdateMeshIfNeeded() function

ar_meshCollider.sharedMesh = m_Mesh;            //(used for collision detection)
```